# Replace a XML pattern using SED

Tags: xml, awk, sed

I have below XML

```
<defns:Code typeCode="Name">
John
</defns:Code>
<defns:Code1 typeCode="ID">
12345
</defns:Code1>
<defns:Code2 typeCode="address">
Addresss 1234
</defns:Code2>
<defns:Text typeCode="Name">
Doe
</defns:Text>
<defns:Text2 typeCode="ID">
 123
</defns:Text2>
<defns:Text3 typeCode="Address">
Address 4567
</defns:Text3>
```

and so on
element Code[1..n],Text[1..n] in the file has to be replaced with Code

```
<defns:Code typeCode="Name">
John
</defns:Code>
<defns:Code typeCode="ID">
12345
</defns:Code>
<defns:Code typeCode="address">
Addresss 1234
</defns:Code>
<defns:Text typeCode="Name">
Doe
</defns:Text>
<defns:Text typeCode="ID">
 123
</defns:Text>
<defns:Text typeCode="Address">
Address 4567
</defns:Text>
```

Can this be done using SED or AWK. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Don't use regex-based tools to parse or manipulate XML.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use sed:

```
s@\(</*defns:Code\)[0-9]*@\1@
```

That strips trailing digits by replacing the prefix plus the digits with only the prefix.